# Java SingletonImmutableList iterating with iterator not foreach?

Tags: java, list, collections, foreach, iterator

I've found this code:

```
public CMNavigation parsePath(List<String> segments) {

    if (segments.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }
    // resolve first URL segment to site root channel
    Iterator<String> it = segments.iterator();
    CMNavigation rootNavigation = lookupRootSegment(it.next());
    if (rootNavigation == null) {
      return null;
    }
    Content content = rootNavigation.getContent();
    // iterate over next segments and find the respective navigation child
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      String segment = it.next();
      List<Content> candidates = content.getLinksFulfilling("children", "segment = ?0", segment);
      if (candidates.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
      }
      content = candidates.get(0);
    }
    return contentBeanFactory.createBeanFor(content, CMNavigation.class);
  }
```

Don't care much about the context. 
I just like to know why "segments" which is of type **SingletonImmutableList** is here being iterated through by a while loop plus the iterator given by "segments". Why isn't the author using foreach here?
I'd just like to understand this way better and know about the benefits.

Comment: Perhaps this code was written before the enhanced for loop ("foreach") was added in Java 5.

Comment: It's also possible that there was code that did remove from `segments`, but now it's absent

Comment: Well its an immutable list..a removal wouldn't be possible anyway?

Comment: First of all, this is a `public` method having a parameter of type `List`. At no place, there is any assumption about the list’s type being a `SingletonImmutableList`. You are only looking at one particular call site which happens to pass a list of that specific type as method argument. The reason why an explicit `Iterator` is used, is obviously, because the first list element is processed differently than the others. A for-each loop doesn’t simplify such a scenario, but is suitable if all elements are handled the same way.